# 'invalid controlling predicate' error when compiled with-fopenmp

Tags: c, openmp

```
void random(int M,int a,int c,int *seq,int start,int size)
{
 int i = start;
 seq[0] = 1;
 seq[i] = (a * seq[i - size] + c) % M;
 i += size;
}

for(int iter = 0;iter < ceil((double)(n/size));iter++)
{      
  random(M,a,c,seq,1,1);    
}
```

The loop compiled with `-fopenmp` and `gcc` gives "invalid controlling predicate" error.
How to solve it?

Comment: shouldn't `ceil((double)(n/size))` be an integer? I mean "as a type". And `(double)(n/size)` won't achieve anything useful if `n` and `size` are integers...

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no OpenMP constructs in the code shown, therefore compiling with or without `-fopenmp` should not affect it. But if there was a `[parallel] for` construct, then it will fail as the type of `ceil()` is `double` and OpenMP only allows integer types in loops.

You have to coerce the result from `ceil()` to an integer:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int iter = 0; iter < (int)ceil((double)n/size); iter++)
{      
   random(M,a,c,seq,1,1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have produced an example from your code that I can correctly compile (I did not 
try to execute it).

I can compile it with the following command (please note the `-lm` linker option):

```
gcc -fopenmp <<example_name>>.c -lm
```

The code is;

```
#include <math.h>

int n = 1;
int size = 2;
int M, a, c;
int *seq;

void random(int M,int a,int c,int *seq,int start,int size)
{
   int i = start;
   seq[0] = 1;
   seq[i] = (a * seq[i - size] + c) % M;
   i += size;
}

int main()
{
   double iter = 0;
   for(;iter < ceil((double)(n/size));iter++)
   {      
      random(M,a,c,seq,1,1);    
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code contains no OpenMP constructs and therefore compiles with `-fopenmp`. The original post is missing a crucial bit of information, most likely a `#pragma omp parallel for` line.